# jQuery Extend Bootstrap-DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you $.extend the [Bootstrap-DateTimePicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/v4beta/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js).  I've been reading the jQuery docs and posts on stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to figure out how to override portions of the plugin with some minor changes.

```
(function($) {

var extensionMethods = {

    place: function(){
        console.log("Extended")
    }
};

$.extend(true, $.fn.datetimepicker.prototype, extensionMethods);


})(jQuery);
```